# Richfaces-bundled jQuery is included after webapp-bundled JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces, facelets

I recently upgraded my Richfaces library to **4.2.2.Final** and I noticed that **the jquery library bundled with Richfaces is now located below my custom scripts making them unusable**.

Here is the resulting html:

```
<head><title lang="fr">Massaï, bronze, 2008 / Jean-Baptiste Martin Sculptures</title>
                <meta name="description" content="Sculpture en bronze d'une femme massai. 2008." lang="fr" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="Jean-Baptiste Martin, sculpture, sculpteur, oeuvre, bronze, portrait, statue, tête, visage, plâtre, moule, moulage, fonte, modèle, modelage, nu" lang="fr" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/favicon-32x32.png" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/carousel.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
                <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
                <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/jcarousellite_1.0.1.js"></script>
                <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/init-sculpture.js"></script>
                <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.formulaire-inscription.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js.jsf?ln=javax.faces"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/jquery.js.jsf"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/richfaces.js.jsf"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/richfaces-queue.js.jsf"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/richfaces-base-component.js.jsf"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/richfaces-event.js.jsf"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/component-control.js.jsf?ln=org.richfaces"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/popupPanel.js.jsf?ln=org.richfaces"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/popupPanelBorders.js.jsf?ln=org.richfaces"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/popupPanelSizer.js.jsf?ln=org.richfaces"></script><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/rfRes/popupPanel.ecss.jsf?db=eAG7mShzEgAFjAIg&amp;ln=org.richfaces" /><script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/status.js.jsf?ln=org.richfaces"></script>
</head>
```

Here is the corresponding facelets:

```
 <h:head>
        <ui:insert name="title-bar-title" />
        <ui:insert name="meta-description"/>
        <meta name="keywords" content="#{msg['meta.mots.clefs']}" lang="#{view.locale.language}"/>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/images/favicon-32x32.png" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/css/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/css/carousel.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <ui:insert name="javascript"/>
    </h:head>
```

Can anyone please help me sort this problem?

EDIT: Here is the corresponding js:

```
    <ui:define name="javascript">
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/js/jquery.mousewheel.js"/>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"  src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/js/jcarousellite_1.0.1.js"/>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"  src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/js/init-sculpture.js"/>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"  src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/js/jquery.formulaire-inscription.js"/>
    </ui:define>
```

EDIT: after modifying as advised:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/favicon-32x32.png" /><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/javax.faces.resource/css/screen.css.jsf" /><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/javax.faces.resource/css/layout.css.jsf" /><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/javax.faces.resource/css/carousel.css.jsf" /><script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/js/jquery.mousewheel.js.jsf"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/js/jcarousellite_1.0.1.js.jsf"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/js/init-sculpture.js.jsf"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/js/jquery.formulaire-inscription.js.jsf"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js.jsf?ln=javax.faces"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/jquery.js.jsf"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/richfaces.js.jsf"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/richfaces-queue.js.jsf"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/richfaces-base-component.js.jsf"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/richfaces-event.js.jsf"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/component-control.js.jsf?ln=org.richfaces"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/popupPanel.js.jsf?ln=org.richfaces"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/popupPanelBorders.js.jsf?ln=org.richfaces"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/popupPanelSizer.js.jsf?ln=org.richfaces"></script><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/rfRes/popupPanel.ecss.jsf?db=eAG7mShzEgAFjAIg&amp;ln=org.richfaces" /><script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/status.js.jsf?ln=org.richfaces"></script>
```

EDIT: The modified facelet:

```
<h:head>
    <ui:insert name="title-bar-title" />
    <ui:insert name="meta-description" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="#{msg['meta.mots.clefs']}" lang="#{view.locale.language}" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/images/favicon-32x32.png" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/screen.css"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/layout.css"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/carousel.css"/>
    <h:outputScript name="js/jquery.mousewheel.js" target="head"/>
    <h:outputScript name="js/jcarousellite_1.0.1.js" target="head"/>
    <h:outputScript name="js/init-sculpture.js" target="head"/>
    <h:outputScript name="js/jquery.formulaire-inscription.js" target="head"/>
</h:head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the JSF resource management the right way.

**Remove** the

```
<ui:insert name="javascript"/>
```

And **replace** the clumsy

```
<ui:define name="javascript">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/js/jquery.mousewheel.js"/>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"  src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/js/jcarousellite_1.0.1.js"/>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"  src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/js/init-sculpture.js"/>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"  src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/js/jquery.formulaire-inscription.js"/>
</ui:define>
```

by the simpler (just put in template that way so that it end up in `<h:body>`)

```
<h:outputScript name="js/jquery.mousewheel.js" target="head" />
<h:outputScript name="js/jcarousellite_1.0.1.js" target="head" />
<h:outputScript name="js/init-sculpture.js" target="head" />
<h:outputScript name="js/jquery.formulaire-inscription.js" target="head" />
```

*after* you've moved the `/js` folder into the `/resources` folder of the public webcontent.

```
WebContent
 |-- resources
 |    `-- js
 |         |-- jquery.mousewheel.js
 |         |-- jcarousellite_1.0.1.js
 |         |-- init-sculpture.js
 |         `-- jquery.formulaire-inscription.js
 :
```

Comment: Thanks BalusC. I have modified my page as advised. The problem remains unfortunately: custom scripts are included above the jquery library...

Comment: They should go in `<h:body>`, not in `<h:head>`. Then they will be relocated to the very end of `<head>`.